# How to make the robot follows exactly the global plan?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to make my robot to follow the path planned by the global planner and completely ignore the local planner.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220106/how-to-make-the-robot-follows-exactly-the-global-plan?/) by [Ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/24948/ahmed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can increase `pdist_scale` parameter value. It is distance-to-path scoring weight. Its default value is **0.6**. You may try values like **0.8**, or **0.9**. For the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3